# Classe não encontrada, mas em outro projeto funcionava

Tags: laravel-4, composer

Já havia inserido a Class `Agent` em um outro projeto utilizando o Laravel 4, estava tudo funcionando tudo corretamente, mas agora que estou tentando colocar em outro projeto o Laravel está retornando o erro:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider' not found
```

Ele fala que não encontrou o arquivo sendo que está tudo correto:

[image: erro]

No arquivo `app/config/app.php`, eu inseri as linhas como está escrito no [GitHub](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-Agent)... Mesmo assim está dando esse erro. Alguém sabe onde posso estar errando?

Comment: instalou pelo composer?
Fez isso?
em app/config/app.php:
   'Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider',

em app/config/app.php:
   'Agent' => 'Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent',

Comment: @DanielLemes, inseri os arquivos manualmente e alterei os arquivos como está escrito no projeto no `GitHub`. Fiz tudo isso e no ´cmd´ eu dei um `composer update` na pasta do projeto...

Comment: coloca o 
"require": {
        "jenssegers/agent": "*"
}
no teu composer.json então

Comment: tu pode tentar dar um composer dump-autoload antes

Comment: @DanielLemes, coloquei dessa forma como está escrito no `GitHub`, melhor dizendo, fiz tudo do mesmo jeito mesmo assim está dando esse erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão:

1. Remova completamente a pasta `vendor/jenssegers`
2. Na linha de comando (*cmd*), vá para a pasta do projeto (`laravel-master`)
3. Execute o comando `composer selfupdate` para atualizar o seu *composer*
4. Execute o comando `composer require jenssegers/agent`
5. Se o comando acima falhar, acrescente `"jenssegers/agent": "*"` na seção `require` do seu arquivo `composer.json`, caso ainda não esteja lá
6. Execute o comando `composer update -o jenssegers/agent`

Se ainda não funcionar, por favor inclua o conteúdo de `composer.json` na sua pergunta, para que nos ajude no diagnóstico.

Answer (score -1):

Precisa dar um `composer dump-autoload` no terminal. Assim ele gerará os arquivos de autoload novamente.